# Defining four indexes Versus defining one index on the search fields

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an employee table that have the following columns:

```
employeeID (PK)
First_name
    Last_name
    Third_name
    Age
    Sex
    Telephone
    Dateofbirth
    Position
```

And i have a search functionality to search for the employee using any of these fields:-

```
First_name
Last_name
Telephone
Dateofbirth
```

**And the user can specify any combinations of these fields to be included for the search.**

Now to improve the search what is the best way to create indexes ,, should i :-

1. create separate four indexes on the four search fields?

**OR**

1. it will be better to create a single index that contains the four columns together?

**OR**

1. there is a third better solution?

BR

Comment: An index on `(First_name,Last_Name,Telephone,DateOfBirth)` will **not** help you when searching for just a `last_name` alone. It can only ever be used if the n left-most columns are used. So one index with four columns is typically rather pointless - unless you have lots of queries that **always** use all four columns...

Answer (score 2):

The second option (one index on all four columns) is not very likely to be useful unless you know that users always include one column, almost always include a second column, etc. Any query that doesn't look at the first column in an index isn't going to make use of that index, at least for the purpose of index seek. Such an index still might be used to retrieve the data in those cases, if no other columns are included in the select list.

Whether all four indexes are necessary, I'm not sure. Is it really likely that a search for first name will occur without last name? How often do you think users will search for John? I'd let those scan and combine them as a single index `(LastName,FirstName)`. I'd also be surprised if you had many searches for birth date. Is it really common practice where employees will know (or can easily find out) their co-workers' age / birthday?

Comment: so you mean i should only include first & last name as the search fields ,, and then define a singlt index for these two fields?

Comment: I don't know if *you* should. That's probably what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really an ideal solution using traditional indices.  If you think about how it works, an index is really like sorting the table against a specific field.  So if you only have one index with all four columns, it can only really use the first one anyway.  If you use four indices, then SQL Server can search against each one in sequence.

However, the above is moot if you're searching against a wildcard patterns:

```
COLUMN LIKE '%searchstring%'
```

That search cannot use the index-- it will have to search the contents of each row.

All of which suggests that you should consider a full-text index, which is meant for exactly this kind of scenario.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx